# Get the ClientID of a div container in aspx page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, clientid

I need to get the client id from a contentplaceholder on an aspx page... I know a div is not a control, but I was wondering if  there was a way to do this outside of the master page. (Code displayed is not in Master).
This just tells me that 'map' does not exist:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
<div id="map" style="height:320px !important; width:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('<%= map.ClientID %>'));
    </script>
```

Comment: Since it isn't a server control, you can just use. `alert(document.getElementById('map'));` The ClientID part is for a control with `runat="server"` on it when you aren't using a `ClientIDMode="static"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to include the jquery-1.10.2.js set of files.

Anyhoos you can select on a class like:

```
$(".myclass")
```

and you can get the id like:

```
$(".map").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a 'runat=server' tag to your div:

```
<div id="map" style="height:320px !important; width:100%;" Runat="server"></div>
```

Now your code will work

Answer (score 0):

You can also try jQuery [attribute=value] Selector

```
$("[id$=map]")
```